# How to delete an invalid requirement from venv? (pycharm?)

Tags: python, opencv, pip, python-venv

I have tried to do the standard

`pip freeze > requirements.txt` and got

> Could not parse requirement: -pencv-python

I then found out pip actually thinks this is the installed package

[image]

Notice the 1st line.

How do I get rid of this and get a requirements file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, `venv\Lib\site-packages` had a folder `~pencv_python-4.2.0.34.dist-info`, which was unused, due to `opencv_contrib_python-4.2.0.34.dist-info` also being present.

I removed it and it worked.

Windows, if anyone cares.